# initializer for conditional binding must have optional type

Tags: swift

I want to create a BLE scanner, and follow Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift) at developer.apple.com,

when session "Create a Table View", I got an error here,

BLEMember.swift

```
import UIKit

class BLEMember {
    var rssi: Int
    var uuid: String

    init (rssi:Int, uuid:String){
      self.rssi = rssi
      self.uuid = uuid
    }
}
```

BLEScanTableViewController.swift

```
...
    private func loadBLEMembers() {

    var members = [BLEMember]()
    guard let member1 = BLEMember(rssi: 65, uuid: "testing ble 1") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal1")
    }

    guard let member2 = BLEMember(rssi: 35, uuid: "testing ble 2") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
    }

    guard let member3 = BLEMember(rssi: 45, uuid: "testing ble 3") else {
        fatalError("Unable to instantiate meal2")
    }

    members += [member1, member2, member3]
}
```

and error happen,

```
 initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not "BLEMember"
```

how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let member1 = BLEMember(rssi: 65, uuid: "testing ble 1")` always success. You don't need use guard here!

```
private func loadBLEMembers() {

    var members = [BLEMember]()
    let member1 = BLEMember(rssi: 65, uuid: "testing ble 1")

    let member2 = BLEMember(rssi: 35, uuid: "testing ble 2")

    let member3 = BLEMember(rssi: 45, uuid: "testing ble 3")

    members += [member1, member2, member3]

}
```

Comment: readmore about [guard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) here!